# How to find related post from title and content - PHP and Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, related-content

I am trying to fetch related contents from Mysqli DB. It is easy to fetch by Like %%, but that doesn't output required related contents.

I want to have related post, similar to title and content.

Structure: title - text and content - long text

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') AS score
FROM articles 
WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$title = $row['title'];
echo $title;
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

But that doesn't output anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable `Full Text` for title and use this code: its pesudo code

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') AS score
FROM articles 
WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('$CurrentPostTitle') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```

i hope to help you